# Effectively Fetching NFT Metadata From Backend

Tags: nft, metadata

I'm building a platform that requires constant fetching of NFT Metadata, is there a cheaper alternative than depending on an 3rd Party paid API? Or am I stuck Scraping and storing NFT metadata into some database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u specify what metadata you want ?

If you are using a metaplex standard nft , then you can fetch metadata from token metadata account that is derived from mint account .

U can see the fields in the image ..[image]